# What is <!-- EVENT overall_footer_content_after--> and what does it do?

Tags: html, phpbb

I can guess what`<!-- INCLUDE navbar_footer.html -->`,`<!-- IF TRANSLATION_INFO -->`,`<!-- ENDIF -->` and `<!-- INCLUDEJS forum_fn.js -->` do.

But what is `<!-- EVENT overall_footer_content_after -->`, what is its purpose?

this is the is the file /styles/latte/template/overall_footer.html

```
        <!-- EVENT overall_footer_content_after -->
    </div>

<!-- EVENT overall_footer_page_body_after -->

<div id="page-footer" class="page-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <!-- INCLUDE navbar_footer.html -->

    <div class="copyright">
        <!-- EVENT overall_footer_copyright_prepend -->
        {CREDIT_LINE}
        <!-- IF TRANSLATION_INFO --><br />{TRANSLATION_INFO}<!-- ENDIF -->
        <!-- EVENT overall_footer_copyright_append -->
        <!-- IF DEBUG_OUTPUT --><br />{DEBUG_OUTPUT}<!-- ENDIF -->
        <!-- IF U_ACP --><br /><strong><a href="{U_ACP}">{L_ACP}</a> 
</strong><!-- ENDIF -->
    </div>

    <div id="darkenwrapper" class="darkenwrapper" data-ajax-error-title="{L_AJAX_ERROR_TITLE}" data-ajax-error-text="{L_AJAX_ERROR_TEXT}" data-ajax-error-text-abort="{L_AJAX_ERROR_TEXT_ABORT}" data-ajax-error-text-timeout="{L_AJAX_ERROR_TEXT_TIMEOUT}" data-ajax-error-text-parsererror="{L_AJAX_ERROR_TEXT_PARSERERROR}">
        <div id="darken" class="darken">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div id="phpbb_alert" class="phpbb_alert" data-l-err="{L_ERROR}" data-l-timeout-processing-req="{L_TIMEOUT_PROCESSING_REQ}">
        <a href="#" class="alert_close">
            <i class="icon fa-times-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <h3 class="alert_title">&nbsp;</h3><p class="alert_text"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="phpbb_confirm" class="phpbb_alert">
        <a href="#" class="alert_close">
            <i class="icon fa-times-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="alert_text"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<div>
    <a id="bottom" class="anchor" accesskey="z"></a>
    <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT -->{RUN_CRON_TASK}<!-- ENDIF -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{T_JQUERY_LINK}"></script>
<!-- IF S_ALLOW_CDN --><script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('\x3Cscript src="{T_ASSETS_PATH}/javascript/jquery.min.js?assets_version={T_ASSETS_VERSION}">\x3C/script>');</script><!-- ENDIF -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{T_ASSETS_PATH}/javascript/core.js?assets_version={T_ASSETS_VERSION}"></script>
<!-- INCLUDEJS forum_fn.js -->
<!-- INCLUDEJS ajax.js -->
<!-- IF S_ALLOW_CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
            var $fa_cdn = $('head').find('link[rel="stylesheet"]').first(),
                $span = $('<span class="fa" style="display:none"> </span>').appendTo('body');
                if ($span.css('fontFamily') !== 'FontAwesome' ) {
                    $fa_cdn.after('<link href="{T_ASSETS_PATH}/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">');
                $fa_cdn.remove();
            }
            $span.remove();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<!-- ENDIF -->

<!-- IF S_COOKIE_NOTICE -->
    <script src="{T_ASSETS_PATH}/cookieconsent/cookieconsent.min.js?assets_version={T_ASSETS_VERSION}"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        window.cookieconsent.initialise({
            "palette": {
                "popup": {
                    "background": "#0F538A"
                },
                    "button": {
                        "background": "#E5E5E5"
                    }
                },
                "theme": "classic",
                "content": {
                    "message": "{LA_COOKIE_CONSENT_MSG}",
                    "dismiss": "{LA_COOKIE_CONSENT_OK}",
                    "link": "{LA_COOKIE_CONSENT_INFO}",
                    "href": "{LA_COOKIE_CONSENT_HREF}"
                }
            })});
    </script>
<!-- ENDIF -->

<!-- EVENT overall_footer_after -->

<!-- IF S_PLUPLOAD --><!-- INCLUDE plupload.html --><!-- ENDIF -->
{$SCRIPTS}

<!-- EVENT overall_footer_body_after -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: read the docs!??

Answer (score 2):

phpBB 3.1.x introduces system of events throughout the code base and template files that allow extensions to use listeners to add features, inject code and modify existing functionality or behavior...

The event:

```
 <!-- EVENT overall_footer_content_after -->
```

was introduced with phpBB 3.1.0-a3 and  the purpose for it is to allow to add content on all pages after the main content, before the footer.